# Remote Performance Monitoring SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance-monitoring, sql-server-2008-r2, perfmon

I've got a couple of servers running SQL Server 2005 Enterprise and I'd like to monitor them remotely using Perfmon (Windows' Performance Monitor).

On my machine, I have an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer, and I noticed that there are a bunch of SQL Server specific performance counters, like MSSQL:Buffer Manager, MSSQL:Databases, MSSQL:Memory Manager, MSSQL:Transactions, MSSQL:Wait Statistics, etc.

If I connect to both servers using Remote Desktop and open Perfmon at the server, I can see all those counters.
When I connect to the server from my machine directly via Perfmon (not using remote desktop) and select counters from the remote computer (\SERVERNAME), I can see all kinds of performance counters (like .NET CLR Jit, Networking, Processes, etc.), but not those from SQL Server.

Please note that I'm using a domain login that has admin permissions on the server.

Do I have to enable something on the server that allows me to monitor the SQL Server's specific performance counters? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are the versions of your SQL server and your remote monitor machine? If your remote monitor machine is 32 bit and your sql server is 64 bit, perhaps you cannot consume the SQL performance counters remotely. [This MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa371636) explained the reason.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, my local machine is running a x86 client version of Windows and the server is running x64. If I had one more point I'd upvote you, but unfortunately I can't :)